# How do you submit parameters from a input tag into a form onsubmit attribute in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 3 inputs, and I want to put their values into the form onsubmit attribute function. Here's my current code. I would like a way to do this that won't require me to create 3 variables using `getElementById()` or `querySelector()`, preferably in the HTML file, but if it's impossible, I'll accept defeat.

```
    <form id="form" onsubmit="addUserCredentials(userID, username, email)">
      <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID"></input>
        <label for="userID">User ID</label>
      
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username"></input>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
      
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></input>
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>

      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**p.s. here's script.js if you want to look (and yes, i'm using firebase)**

```
function addUserCredentials(userId, username, email) {
  db.ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: username,
    email: email
  });
}
```

Comment: by the way, this is my first question, comment if it was structured wrongly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form field values to a Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441375/submit-form-field-values-to-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs will always be available in the form object with its name as the key and does not require to be passed as parameters so,

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="addUserCredentials()">
```

```js
function addUserCredentials() {
  const userId = this.userID.value
  const username = this.username.value
  const email = this.email.value
}
```

`this` as the form element.

Comment: oh, this is an interesting way. i think i'll use this.